# Right side Related Products bar Loaded Twice

Tags: magento-1.7, sidebar

I am running a magento product with own theme. Enabled related products on catalog/layouts/catalog.xml. But in my product view page it is showing twice.

I found few more posts with duplicating content twice (description, etc..) I followed all steps. But still I cant guess how does the related product tab showing twice.

I have below lines in my theme `/app/design/frontend/default/MYTHEME/catalog.xml`

```
<reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

there is no locale.xml as well.. But magically even when i removed above two lines related products are being loaded.

Comment: Is it 100% the same block or not?

Comment: just chage the block name catalog.product.related to catalog.product.relatednew in xml

Comment: @Thomas yes 100% same block. Its exact replication. If I change in the file it reflects in both the places

Comment: @AmitBera i guess it is not taking the app/design/frontend/default/MYTHEME/layout/catalog.xml value, even if i remove the xml file its working fine. So my doubt is, since magento have different layers is there any possibility to access catalog.xml othere than my theme layout folder?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have another reference in another layout file somewhere. Just do find block name in your theme directory via your editor and see if anything comes up.

Have you used widgets to implement that related block?

You could try adding

```
<action method="unsetChildren"/>
```

on the right structural block in your local.xml theme file, then add your related block. This will of course get rid of anything in the right block.

Comment: You are right. When I removed the block inclusion from config.xml it disappeared from the view page. Now I confused other than this from where this block is being loaded?

Comment: could you clarify what config.xml file you edited as that should not be a theme related file. You will need to do a search for the block name in all files and do a bit of trial and error. It could be referenced in a module somewhere

Comment: sorry its catalog.xml